# STM32 program not executing

Tags: microcontroller, c, programming, stm32

I am currently trying to make my own stm32 development board. i have stm32f100c4t6 microcontroller mounted on pcb. 
   I am using Atollic True studio free edition. i had made small blink led program as below.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include "stm32f10x.h"

void delay(int count)
{
    volatile int i;

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
    }
}

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

int main(void)
{
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_3 | GPIO_Pin_4 | GPIO_Pin_5 | GPIO_Pin_6 ;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    while (1)
    {
        delay(100000);
        GPIOA->BSRR = 0xF << 3;
        delay(100000);
        GPIOA->BRR = 0xF << 3;
    }
}
```

I have used st flash loader demonstrator under windows to load program to flash memory. however it detects the flash memory size as 32 KB whereas actually it has 16 KB. but program loaded to flash and verified successfully. (it detects device ID as 0x420 which is for medium density value line whereas this microcontroller is low-density value line.)

When i change the jumper setting of BOOT0 to ground to put it in execution mode, nothing happens. the pin PA3 to P6 remains at 0v.  i have connected 24 MHz crystal as main crytal and 32.768KHz as RTC crystal. I can get voltages around 1.8v at 24 MHz crystal. the other crystal pins remains at 0v. is this wrong?

I have also tried stm32flash under linux to load program, it loads and verify the program sucessfully. but, it also detects microcontroller as mediam density value line (128 KB).

I am stuck at this situation. any help would be appreciable.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: I have attached link of 
 [schematic](http://s16.postimg.org/seplqtx45/stm32.png).

Comment: I think we're going to need your schematic - can you upload it somewhere and share a link? Someone will stop by and edit it in.

Comment: A minor comment: I'm not sure if int is capable of handling numbers as big as 100000 (it may very well be). It wouldn't if it's only 16 bit wide. To be sure I would go with int32_t (or uint32_t) instead for the delay function declaration.

Comment: @fm_andreas, you may be right. but i also tried with value 100. but nothing happens.

Comment: Have you tried using JTAG/SWD to test your hardware?

Comment: What about the clock setup? If run like that, the CPU will use the internal RC clock. You have to setup the clock tree.

Comment: @Leon Heller, Sorry i don't have JTAG/SWD to try out.

Comment: That was very silly! Debugging is going to be difficult. See if you can add the connections - there are only two signals for SWD.

Comment: @Blup1980, So i have to setup the clock for both the crystals?

Comment: Use the internal oscillator for initial testing, it makes things much easier.

Comment: @JaydeepDhrangdhariya - it would be a good idea to buy one of the STM Discovery boards.  They will provide you both an inexpensive known-good platform to test your software, and they also function as SWD programmers/debug interfaces.  You can generally use any STM32 Discovery board with any STM32 chip, even if the part you wish to program is not the same sub-family as the target chip provided on the discovery board.  Last I checked, these were cheaper than logic-level USB serial cables..

Comment: The code you posted should work. I suspect the problem lies somewhere in either the startup code (which should come with the compiler) or some settings in the compiler/linker. As others have suggested, keep it simple, use the built-in oscillators first, and get a debugging interface.

Comment: I don't think that the C compiler has to honor `volatile` on a variable that is not accessible from any other context (is local and its address isn't passed anywhere). I'd check the machine code  that the delay loop is really there.

Comment: Have you tried any other sample code provided with Compiler? Once I had simillar issue.... It was issue with Compiler settings! (P.S. It was a differnt compiler)

Comment: @fm_andreas Since this is a 32 bit 2's complement system, int will hold all positive values up to `(2^32)/2 - 1` = 2.147 billion. But `uint32_t` is indeed to prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simplest possible LED flasher program that works on the STM32VL Discovery board:

```
/* Test.c
** Simple program for STM32F100RB to flash LED on PC_9
**
*/

#include <stm32f10x.h>

void delay(void);

void main(void)
{
  // I/O port C clock enable
  RCC->APB2ENR = RCC_APB2ENR_IOPCEN;
  // Set PC_9 to output 
  GPIOC->CRH &= ~(GPIO_CRH_MODE9 | GPIO_CRH_CNF9);
  GPIOC->CRH |= GPIO_CRH_MODE9;

  while(1)
  {
    GPIOC->BSRR = (1<<9);
    delay();
    GPIOC->BRR = (1<<9);
    delay();
  }
}

void delay(void)
{
  volatile unsigned int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use default clock configuration, you should connect 8 MHz crystal (or 25MHz for Connectivity line chips) to your chip.

A code snippet from `system_stm32f10x.c` in function **SetSysClockTo24()**.

```
#elif defined (STM32F10X_LD_VL) || defined (STM32F10X_MD_VL) || defined (STM32F10X_HD_VL)
    /*  PLL configuration:  = (HSE / 2) * 6 = 24 MHz */
```

Hope that helps.